# Reset (Clear) A PHP Generated DropDownList selection (selected value) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I have been using a javascript (reset) function, to successfully reset the 'selected' option to Index '0' (or option 'None'), in a standard, html select-option DropDown list.

But I cannot seem to get the function to do the same thing in my php-generated version (where the values are imported via an array).

STANDARD SELECT_OPTION LIST:

```
<select id="fruitSalad">

<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="Apples">Apples</option>
<option value="Bananas">Bananas</option>
<option value="Cantaloupes">Cantaloupes</option>

</select>
```

PHP GENERATED SELECT_OPTION LIST:

```
    <?php
            $fruit_selected = "$fruitSalad";
            $fruit_options = array('None', 'Apples', 'Bananas', 'Cantaloupes' );
            echo "<select id='fruitSalad' name='fruitSalad'>";
            foreach($fruit_options as $fruit_option){
                if($fruit_selected == $fruit_option) {
                    echo "<option selected='selected'>$fruit_option</option>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<option>$fruit_option</option>";
                }
            }
            echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

JAVASCRIPT (Reset Function) & Reset Button:

```
    <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" onclick="Reset();" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Reset() {
            var dropDown = document.getElementById("fruitSalad");
            dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Store the default selected index on DOMContentLoaded, and use that index instead of the hardcoded zero.

Comment: Your PHP generated version doesn't add an explicit `value` for `option`s, which default to the text. Your `0` index therefore doesn't exist.

Comment: @MarkusAO Nope, options have a corresponding index despite of missing value attributes.

Comment: @MarkusAO That shouldn't be a problem since that's the _index_, `0` would be the first option

Comment: Markus AO... Thank you. Yes, I do understand that. I just haven't figured out how to make up for that. :)

Comment: @Teemu I am not familiar with DOMCContentLoaded method, but I am trying to find resources and read up on it now. Thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, seems to be working just fine. Clicking "Reset" sets the `<select>` back to `None`

Comment: @DarthCoder It's not a method, it's an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: @Teemu right you are, I was thinking "numeric or named", but there's a numeric index regardless. In that case, OP's code seems like it should work?

Comment: @brombeer You're saying you're getting the php generated version to reset to 'None' using my posted code?

Comment: @DarthCoder Yes, using "only" the code you posted, no HTML, no form, on replit.com

Comment: @brombeer Well then, now I am completely stumped. Because there is nothing different about what I posted, from what I am testing over here. (head scratching)

Comment: Inspect the HTML in your browser and also see console for any javascript errors. It's possible your PHP version outputs some invalid JS prior to this code, and the JS processing halts.

Comment: Nothing in your browser console? Where is `$fruitSalad` set? Have you tried shift-reloading your page? Maybe close/open your browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to put this on hold for a few hours. But I appreciate all of the input and will come back and explore all of your suggestions when I can. I am encouraged by the fact that brombeer said he got it to work for him. So hopefully there is a simple conflict somewhere on my end.

Comment: I had a chance to tinker with this again. As brombeer stated, the example I posted actually DOES work when I isolated it and tested it alone.

However, in my actual code, on my site... for some odd reason, it did not like the ID (example: fruitSalad) being the same as the imported value (example: $fruitSalad). 

So, I changed the ID and now it works perfectly. Thank you all for your help!